# Preview could not be loaded issue/error in elementor

Tags: wordpress, templates, elementor

I'm working with a custom template and when I try to open any page in elementor plugin after selecting my template for that page, it shows me an error: "preview could not be loaded" and I have to enable safe mood in order to open that page in the elementor.

**Template code:-**

```
<?php 
/**
    Template name: Master Template  
*/
wp_head();
get_header();
?>

<body>
    
<?php 
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
</body>

<?php 
get_footer();
?>
```

I found 2 solutions regarding this
**Solution 1:-**

> Before going further, 99% of the time, this error usually caused by
> running out of memory. To resolve this, you must increase the PHP
> memory_limit variable. The recommended memory limit is 512MB. Do this.

**Solution 2:-**

> Deativate all plugins and activate them one by one to see if one of them is conflicting

These solutions didn't work for me, regarding solution 1 I already have memory_limit 512MB and regarding solution 2 There is only 1 plugin activate that is elementor.
What should I do to get rid of this error? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution:-

The error vanished as I changed my current theme, I was using the theme: Twenty Twenty but when I changed it from Twenty Twenty to Twenty Seventeen the error was gone and my plugin elementor started working like a charm.

When I debugged it deeply I came to know that I didn't use
wp_footer() with get_footer(), as I used this function(in old/using theme), issue was vanished.

**Code is below:-**

```
<?php 
/**
    Template name: Master Template  
*/
wp_head();
get_header();
?>

<body>
    
<?php 
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
</body>

<?php 
get_footer();
wp_footer();
?>
```

Hope it'll help someone.